# WaitForExit process ends when application lose focus

Tags: c#, process

I'm trying to do something like this :

```
var process = Process.Start("MyGame.exe");
process.WaitForExit();
MessageBox.Show("Game is closed");
```

The thing  is when I `Alt + Tab` the game my application thinks the game has exited and then displays the message. I want to completely wait for the program to be shut down before the message appears.

Is there a way around this ?

Comment: Does this problem occur for *only* the specific mygame.exe, or do you see it in general?

Comment: Are you sure MyGame.exe isn't actually exiting? It might be spawning a separate executable or something. You can verify this by watching the PID through these transitions.

Comment: How can I know if it's actually exiting ? It shoudn't .. it's a regular game and it's still in the proccess list

Comment: Like I said, you can monitor the PID.

Comment: What I would do is `MessageBox.Show("PID = " + process.Id);` just before you call `WaitForExit()`. Then, after it says the game is closed, you can go into task manager and see what it shows the game's PID is. If it's not the same, then it's not the same process.

Comment: It's not in the sevices section.. so I guess it closes. What can I do ? How is that even possible

Comment: why would it be in the services section ? that tab is for services! is it in the Processes section ?

Comment: I can't find the PID in the process section ill look (sorry not familiar AT ALL with processes)

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk Go to the Processes tab, then click View -> Select Columns. Make sure PID has a tick mark.

Comment: Found it. And no its not the same ID.. so it actually closes... What can I do about this now ? :P

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk You're going to have to check the Processes list after WaitForExit() returns to make sure it's really closed. This is getting a little out of control for this question. I recommend doing a little more research on processes and then asking a separate question if you get stuck.

Comment: isnt't that what i'm doing when using process.WaitForExit ? How can I check otherwise

Answer (score 2):

Alt+Tabbing away from a program that uses DirectX generates a "device lost" error code.  Described in [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb174714%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> By design, the full set of scenarios that can cause a device to become lost is not specified. Some typical examples include loss of focus, **such as when the user presses ALT+TAB** or when a system dialog is initialized. Devices can also be lost due to a power management event, or when another application assumes full-screen operation. In addition, any failure from IDirect3DDevice9::Reset puts the device into a lost state.

This error can be hard to deal with in the game logic since it strikes right in the heart of the game loop.  Apparently the programmer of your game found a very hacky but effective solution: he simply restarts the program.  That gets the program state restored and get the game going again as soon as it re-acquires the display.

A possible workaround is to sleep for a while after WaitForExit() completes, then use Process.GetProcessesByName() to find out if it started back up.  Which gets you a new Project reference, rinse and repeat.